# Export original image not cropped one from sketch

Tags: export, sketch-app

I've added an image to a rectangle as background **fill** and the image is filling the rectangle and is cropped.

Now, our developer wants the original image as an asset for his HTML. How can I make the **original images** exportable not the cropped ones?

Answer (score 1):

You can mask the image with rect without cropping it.

Place your shape under the image (oval in my case):
[image]

Right-click on shape and select Use as Mask:
[image]

Now shape masks your image withou cropping:
[image]

If you want export the original image, just Unmask the shape and Slice the image:
[image]